# How to automaticly redirect http requests to https by cloud code on Parse.com for static files

Tags: express, parse-platform, https, parse-cloud-code, parse.js

My app is almost all static files hosts on cloud code of Parse.com.
I try to redirect http requests to https by using parse-express-https-redirect.
Then serve the static files by 'express.static' method.
My code is very simple:

```
//main.js
require('cloud/app.js');

//app.js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var parseExpressHttpsRedirect = require('parse-express-https-redirect');

app.use(express.static('cloud/static'));
app.use(parseExpressHttpsRedirect());


app.listen();
```

But I got an error when I uploaded it by 'parse deploy':

```
Object function createApplication() {
  var app = connect();
  utils.merge(app, proto);
  app.request = { __proto__: req };
  app.response = { __proto__: res };
  app.init();
  return app;
} has no method 'static'
```

Why do I get this error? Is there any way to do this job?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of express are you using?

Comment: @GrimurD Sorry, I don't know, it's the version at Cloud Code(Parse.com). But I can't find any docs of that. However I believe it's not too old version that doesn't support static method.

Comment: No probably not too old to support it, but the api for it is different between v3 and v4, might want to lookup how it is done in v3, just in case